# Convert HTTPS to HTTP using htaccess file in wordpress to load the mages and the links

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https

I had https on my wordpress website. but today the certificate has been expired.

I changed my wordpress reading setting's URL's to http from https

(WordPress Address (URL) and site url)

Now I can load the site but still some of the images and links are not loading as the srcs contains the https

As there are lots of https, what I want to know is How can I rewrite all the https links to http in my htaccess?

I used this, but not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below line of code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: tnx for theanswer but, I have already redirected users to the http but some images and pdfs still contains https, so I could not load them!!

Comment: The above rule will work for all urls irrespective of PDF or image.Can you share one of such image/pdf url?

Comment: Ex;https://sample.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Layer-2.png to  http://sample.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Layer-2.png first link contain https and second http

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all URLs in the database for images and links that exist in wp_posts, wp_postmeta, etc. An `.htaccess` rewrite rule won't do that.

Remove the redirect and then use [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to find/replace https to http URLs in the database.